# How to configure custom error pages for exceptions in view files?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

We're using `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in combination with a simple custom middleware that sets `Response.StatusCode` to `500`, to successfully to send users to our custom error page on exceptions that occur in mvc controllers.

However, for exceptions that occur in razor/cshtml views, `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` doesn't send the user to our error page (though our custom middleware does detect these exceptions in `Invoke()`).

We tried using an Exception Filter as well, but it only traps exceptions from controller actions, not from views.

Is there a way to send users to our error page if the exception originates in a view?

Comment: FYI, the StatusCodePages middleware only applies to non-500 status codes. Actual exceptions (i.e. things that trigger 500-range status codes) are handled via the ExceptionHandler middleware. In other words, to catch *everything* you need both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StatusCodePagesMiddleware` added by `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` extension call [has the following check](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs) after executing of underlying middlewares:

```
// Do nothing if a response body has already been provided.
if (context.Response.HasStarted
    || context.Response.StatusCode < 400
    || context.Response.StatusCode >= 600
    || context.Response.ContentLength.HasValue
    || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Response.ContentType))
{
    return;
}
```

When rendering of the View starts, MVC middleware fills `Response.ContentType` with `text/html` value. That's why above check returns `true` and request with status code page is not re-executed.

The fix is fair simple. In your middleware that handles exceptions, call `Clear()` method on `Response`:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49757495-Exception-In-View)